# Problema de lista enlazada en C

Tags: c, linux

Tal y como ven en el titulo esta pregunta es sobre listas enlazadas, al intentar resolver un ejercicio que me pide

> implementar una lista enlazada que permita introducir N números aleatorios ordenados a posteriori en la lista enlazada, el variable N es introducido por terminal y después hay que generar N valores aleatorios y introducirlos ordenadamente en la lista.

Existe un cierto problema en el código que he programado, no consigo insertar los elementos en la lista, siendo esta siempre `NULL`.
He seguido los siguientes pasos para la resolución del problema:

1.Crear N valores aleatorios y ordenarlos.

2.Crear un nodo temporal con el primer valor de números aleatorios ordenados n[i] y después introducirlo en la lista, convirtiéndolo en la cabeza de la lista si la lista esta vacía, sino recorremos la lista hasta su ultimo valor y introducirla allí.

Pero no me sale bien por cierta razón que no consigo encontrar.
El problema debe localizarse en `void Inserta(int N,Lista *lista)` ya que es el núcleo de la lista enlazada.

Necesitaría cierta ayudita en la resolución de este problema, aunque posiblemente sea muy sencilla el problema pero como un gran paleto que soy no lo consigo ver.
Gracias por adelantado.

**Código**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Nodo{
    int numero;
    struct Nodo *sig;
} Nodo;

typedef struct Lista{
    Nodo *cabeza;
    int contador;
} Lista;

Nodo *CrearNodo(int n){
    Nodo *nodo = (Nodo *) malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    nodo->numero = n;
    nodo->sig = NULL;
    return nodo;

}

void DestruirNodo(Nodo *nodo);
void GeneraNumeroAleatorio(int N,Lista *lista);
void initialize(Lista *lista);
void display(Nodo *nodo);
void Inserta(int N,Lista *lista);

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    int N;
    Lista *lista;
    lista = malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    initialize(lista);
    N = atoi(argv[1]);
    GeneraNumeroAleatorio(N, lista);
    display(lista->cabeza);

return 0;
}

void initialize(Lista *lista){
    lista->contador = 0;
    lista->cabeza = NULL;
}
void DestruirNodo(Nodo *nodo){
    free(nodo);
}

void GeneraNumeroAleatorio(int N,Lista *lista){

    int i,n[N],j,aux;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        n[i] = 0;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        n[i] = rand() % 11;
    }
    for(i = 1; i < N; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < N-1; j++){
            if(n[j] > n[j+1]){
                aux = n[j];
                n[j] = n[j+1];
                n[j+1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        Inserta(n[i],lista);
    }


}

void Inserta(int N,Lista *lista){
    int i;

        Nodo *nodo = CrearNodo(N);
        if(lista->cabeza == NULL){
            lista->cabeza = nodo;
        }
        else{
            Nodo *puntero = lista->cabeza;
            while(puntero->sig != NULL){//Me muevo a lo largo de la lista hasta llegar al ultimo valor de la lista puntero->sig=NULL//
                puntero = puntero->sig;
            }
            puntero->sig = nodo;
        }
        DestruirNodo(nodo);//Destruyo el nodo generado despues de cada uso/bucle.//
        lista->contador++;//Incrementando el contador en 1 para saber cuantos elementos tengo en la lista//

}
void display(Nodo *nodo){
    if(nodo == NULL)
    {
        printf("NULL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d\n", nodo -> numero);
        display(nodo->sig);
    }
}
```

Comment: Si no es necesario hacerlo de ese modo, puedes usar vectores del header <vector> y te olvidas de la administración de memoria.

Comment: @Mateo No existe el header `<vector>` en C ...

Comment: Gracias por mencionarlo. Estoy demasiado enfocado en C++. Debería hacer algún proyecto en C para tenerlo presente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Inserta(int N,Lista *lista){
    int i;

        Nodo *nodo = CrearNodo(N);
        if(lista->cabeza == NULL){
            lista->cabeza = nodo;
        }
        else{
            Nodo *puntero = lista->cabeza;
            while(puntero->sig != NULL){//Me muevo a lo largo de la lista hasta llegar al ultimo valor de la lista puntero->sig=NULL//
                puntero = puntero->sig;
            }
            puntero->sig = nodo;
        }
        DestruirNodo(nodo);//Destruyo el nodo generado despues de cada uso/bucle.//
        lista->contador++;//Incrementando el contador en 1 para saber cuantos elementos tengo en la lista//

}
```

No tienes que destruir el nodo generado; el nodo debe permanecer.

Cuando haces `lista->cabeza = nodo;` o `punter->sig = nodo`, no copias el nodo a cabeza o sig, lo que copias es **la dirección de memoria**.

Si haces `free` de esa memoria, en cualquier momento el programa puede volver a reclamarla en un `malloc` y usarla para otra cosa; tu estructura no se dará cuenta que está usando un espacio de memoria que ha sido reutilizado.

No hagas `DestruirNodo()` más que para aquellos nodos que no quieras que permanezcan en la lista.